# Rapidly convergent series for $\sum\limits_{J=0}^{\infty} (2 J + 1) e^{-\beta J(J+1)}$ (rigid rotor)

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, power-series, theta-functions

I need to evaluate this series for arbitrary $\beta > 0$:

$ Q = \sum\limits_{J=0}^{\infty} (2 J + 1) e^{-\beta J(J+1)} $

Is it related to a known transcendental function?

From the research I did, it doesn't seem to be so; in which case I would be interested in knowing of good (piecewise?) approximation of it, one that minimizes discontinuities and is monotonic on $\beta$, or an alternative fast converging series (e.g. one that needs less than $\sim\sqrt{1/\beta}$ terms for small $\beta$)

By the way, this is related to the partition function of the quantum rigid rotor.

Bonus: same question for these subseries:

$ Q_\text{even} = \sum\limits_{J=0, J \text{is even}}^{\infty} (2 J + 1) e^{-\beta J(J+1)} $

$ Q_\text{odd } = \sum\limits_{J=1, J \text{is odd}}^{\infty} (2 J + 1) e^{-\beta J(J+1)} $

References to existing numerically implementations are also welcomed.

Comment: These are related to *theta-functions*, q.v.

Comment: Since the integral $\int_0^\infty (2x+1)e^{-\beta x(x+1)}\ dx$ is well convergent and can be explicitly computed you should maybe look at the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula. See here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Maclaurin_summation_formula